# 12V 62 Watt Booster Convereter -circuit inductor and frequency selection?

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, frequency, inductor, boost

How should I select the inductor value and frequency for a 62 watt boost converter? 
My input voltage range is 6V to 12V and i have to maintain a 12.6v output .
I am using an atmega328p microcontroller to generate PWM .

Comment: Frequency mostly depends on the capabilities of the controller chip (which you didn't specify). Then, inductor selection is usually described in details in the controller datasheet/application notes.

Comment: You can get an ATmega to control funciton as boost converter, but you will trade duty cycle steps for frequency. Moreover, since you are implementing it from scratch you must know or choose the switching frequency and calculate all other parameters from there. If you don't know this, or how to implement the analog section, you are better off with a ready made boost converter or module for your application. Also, -1 for lack of capital letter in the start of sentences and punctation, Olin style ;-)

Comment: Please use proper punctuation and format when posting.If you know you are not very good at English.remember to check that your words are spelled correctly.It's already raining with downvotes.I hope you brought an umbrella!

Comment: thanks for downvotes, here i came to solve my problem but i found i choose place ....

Comment: Deepak,it's all about doing the right thing.The first user who downvoted explained himself and I also gave you some tips.The SE network asks for quality content in general.If you correct the mistakes you make  then nobody will downvote you anymore(or retract their downvotes).

Comment: That's a lot of watts for a little microcontroller to be responsible for.  why are you not using a boost converter IC?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you didn't specify the output current. Choose one depending on your application.

As dim mentioned, the frequency can be set depending on how the Atmega is programmed. There are many parameters which affect the correct functioning of the converter, so my post will address simpler calculations. In this case, frequency is a free parameter.

The formula for the inductor is:

L=\$\frac{(V_{out}-V_{in}+V_D)(1-D)}{dIf}\$

Where:

\$V_D\$ is the diode voltage
 D is the duty cycle
dI is inductor ripple current(and \$dI=2I_{load}\$)
f is switching frequency

This means you select your inductor depending on the load current. You may want to bias it to work in continuous mode for stability, where ripple current must be greater than output current multiplied by 2. So calculate your inductor value using your load current, than make sure the inductance is smaller than the result:

L<\$\frac{(V_{out}-V_{in}+V_D)(1-D)}{dIf}\$ for continuous mode

You have to take into account the inductor's saturation voltage and saturation current.These values have to be greater than the peak current and the peak voltage,so it won't unexpectedly clip your output.

Source of information:[Daycounter](http://www.daycounter.com/LabBook/BoostConverter/Boost-Converter-Equations.phtml)
Checked the formulas in the first link with [this](http://ri.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A7x9UkumUGpYFUIAB3dHjAx.;_ylu=X3oDMTByZWJ1c203BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMgRjb2xvA2lyMgR2dGlkAw--/RV=2/RE=1483391270/RO=10/RU=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fan%2Fslva372c%2Fslva372c.pdf/RK=0/RS=zNYG5B1gkX6PFO6mDdocS5VbASM-) PDF

Comment: i have a confusion about inductor ripple current . suppose it is a 63 watt booster then output current require is 5Amp and 12.6V .

Comment: then ripple current must be 10 Amp .   i am calculating from TI Site -http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva372c/slva372c.pdf  ...... here equation 15 i'm using to calculate ripple current . here i have to adjust/change the inductor and frequency  value to get the 10Amp ripple current ?

Comment: Next equation 16 is for  I(maxout) .. here they are using ILIM(min) = minimum value of the current limit of the integrated witch (given in the data sheet) ..then i select one datasheet http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/177/5c0039-75369.pdf   here i select part no. 1540M16  and in column D.C.Amps for 0.8 Ls they mention 5.25 amp....  now ILIM(min)=5.25amp ???? is it correct. i don't know what is this .

Comment: @Deepak ILIM(min) is the minimum limit of the IC current

Comment: @Deepak see edit.What you were looking at was the minimum current limit of the Atmega and its maximum current output.

Comment: atmega  generating only pwm .. which i can control easy then i am connecting BSS123 to pull up the pwm amplitude . that higher amplitude signal goes to mosfet driver (totem poll ). here low site mosfet connected to inductor and schottky diode(20amp)